# How to iterate a protobuffer repeatedfield inside a grpc service?

Tags: c++11, protocol-buffers, grpc

Should I have a mutable reference to the field, I would be able to use:

```proto
enum my_types{
  type_unknown = 0;
  type_one = 1;
  tpye_two = 2;
}
message My_message{
  repeated my_types lotsa_types = 1;
}
message My_response{
  //whatever
}

service My_service{
  rpc my_rpc(My_message) returns (My_response) {}
}
```

```cpp
::grpc::Status My_server::my_rpc(
  ::grpc::ServerContext* context, const ::my_namespace::My_message* request,
  ::my_namespace::My_reply* response
){
  std::cout << "Recieved numbers";
  for(my_types& single_number: *request->mutable_lotsa_types()){
    std::cout << " " << single_number << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

but I can not, because `request` is given by a const modifier via the grpc service call:

```
error: passing ‘const my_namespace::My_message’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

How can the const RepeatedFiled be iterated over?

Comment: `for (my_types single_number : request->lotsa_types())`. Or `const my_types&`, but an enum is cheaper to handle by value.

Comment: I don't have a minimal example of this, but in the generated code, the `.lotsa_types()` is a `RepeatedField<int>`, should a cast be sufficient/safe here?

Comment: Should be, yes. Each int is simply the numerical value of the enum. Why the generated code uses `RepeatedField<int>` and not `RepeatedField<my_types>`, I'm not sure; might have something to do with the fact that `sizeof(my_types)` is non-portable, compiler dependent.

Comment: This I would accept as an answer, can you please write it?